# Case assignment rules in Apex Tests do not run

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, assignment-rules

I have a apex test that asserts that after a certain case is created the owner of this case is a queue. The owner is set via a case assignment rule.

When i run this test class everything works as expected. The assertion says that the owner is a certain queue.

But when i run this test class together with at least 1 more test class the owner of the case is not the expected queue but rather the current user running the tests. This tells me that the case assigment rules weren't triggered.

Does anyone know how to fix this or knows any workaround. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this behavior consistent?  Does it fail every time you run this test class with _any_ other test class?  And does it succeed every time you run this class by itself?

Comment: yes. This behavior is consistent.